# Usage of a new font

Tags: fonts, xetex

I have found a font that I like and I want to use it in XeLaTeX but I have no idea what to do. I have downloaded the specific font and installed it although I don't know if I should have done that. Generally what should I do in in order to use a new font? Do I have to install it? Then what do I have to write in the preamble? Thank you!

Comment: Please add a MWE for see your code and then can help you to improve it for use your font with `xelatex`

Comment: The correct way of "installing" a font depends crucially on the operating system in use on your computer. Please provide some information on that subject.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `fontspec`-package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{<your font name>}

\begin{document}

This text should be set in your new wonder-font

\end{document}
```

You need the font installed on your system, so no harm done there.